# glBlitFramebuffer - glReadBuffer and glDrawBuffer refer to the same buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

Just for learning purposes I test what happens when I call `glBlitFramebuffer` when `glReadBuffer` and `glDrawBuffer` refer to the same buffer. The custom framebuffer is defined this way:

```
bool initFBO()
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);

    glGenTextures(1, &fboTexId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTexId);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTexId, 0);

    GLuint rboDepth;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepth);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, w, h);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is the rendering:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);

render();
//now fboTexId is filled

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w / 2, h / 2, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

//render to the screen
renderTex(fboTexId);
```

When I render a fbo texture to the screen I get the render function result - `glBlitFramebuffer` does nothing. I have expected to get the render function result with the second layer two times smaller on the top. I don't know if calling `glReadBuffer` and `glDrawBuffer` with the same argument is allowed. Should it work as I expected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OpenGL 4.6 Core Profile Specification - [18.3.1 Blitting Pixel Rectangles](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#subsection.18.3.1)

> If the source and destination buffers **are identical**, and the source and destination rectangles overlap, **the result** of the blit operation **is undefined** as described in the introduction to section 18.3.

In your case, not only are the buffers identical but also overlap.

If you want to combine different framebuffers into a single one, you usually have a composition (or background) layer that is the only drawing buffer.

Comment: "Overlap" means that ```glReadBuffer``` and ```glDrawBuffer``` refer to the same framebuffer attachment. What does it mean that  the source and destination buffers are identical ?

Comment: The buffers are **identical** if they refer to the same object, **overlap** is referred to the intersection of the specific rectangles (see quote: _"the source and destination rectangles overlap"_). There should be no problem to read and write from/to a none overlapping part of the buffer (even if io operations are asynchronous).